# multiple types of array list via one method

Tags: android, android-studio, arraylist

How can I pass multiple types of array list via one method

**Code**

```
List<PostsModel> Posts = new ArrayList<>();
List<FavoriteModel> Favorite = new ArrayList<>();
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_posts);
        Posts = LoadArrayList("PostsList"); //Error here
        Favorite = LoadArrayList("FavoriteList"); //Error here
    }

public List<Object> LoadArrayList(String key) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = prefs.getString(key, null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<Object>>() {
    }.getType();
    return gson.fromJson(json, type);
}
```

I have tried a lot but don't work

Comment: what is the problem with your current code

Comment: the error is produced because List<Object> can't be converted directly into List<POST> or List<Favorite>. You need to type cast it manually. for that you need to pass the type information into the loadarraylist function

Comment: @NIKHILMAURYA But I know if I put object then I can send any lists type (unknown)

Comment: I dont want create multi methods for every list , I want one method for all lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the function to

```
public <T> List<T> LoadArrayList(String key, Class<T> type) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = 
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.fromJson(json, type);
}
```

**Call it like**

```
Posts = LoadArrayList("PostsList", PostsModel.class);
```

Comment: what's of the meaning <T> List<T> and why <T> before list and after ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with [Java Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

```
public <T> List<T> loadArrayList(String key) {
    //...
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<T>>() {
    }.getType();
    return gson.fromJson(json, type);
}
```

Now you can do

```
List<PostsModel> Posts = loadArrayList("PostsList");
```

**Explanation**

- First `<T>` in method define a generic type T
- Second T with return type defines the type of returning value.
- You can use any name to variable T, like K, ListType. Usually developers use T for type.

Comment: what's of the meaning <T> List<T> and why <T> before list and after ?